# web.config prevents file downloadable or viewable

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7, web-config

I am very new to ASP.net.
I visited a website long time ago which I cannot remember the URL now. I wanted to open their CSS file to see the source, but once I clicked the error message says, "you don't have premission to act ........."

Now I want to do the same thing to lock up my files. Even visitors could see the file name, but they are unable to open or download it.

I wonder if it is possible to achieve on ASP.net or IIS7?

Many thanks for suggestions.

Comment: This is not possible. If your browser can download the css file and use it, then YOU can see it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.net if you don't want users to open files just add a "_" before the filename.
So instead of: `Mycss.css` write `_Mycss.css`.
This works with all files, and comes very handy when using Layouts, so users can't view your content files.
Also, normally you need permission to open files in you `"~/Content/"` folder, if the request comes from an external source it should write this error you wrote. Try setting permissions to the folder via right click and edit permissions.